# Passing reports through docker in codecov gives error

Tags: docker, code-coverage

I'm trying to setup codecov as code coverage tool in my repository. I referred to this link to pass reports through docker container -

Link - https://github.com/codecov/support/wiki/Testing-with-Docker

But travis ci fails and gives this error -

`docker: Error parsing reference: "..." is not a valid repository/tag.`

Here is my travis.yml

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
language: node_js
node_js:
- 6
before_install:
- export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser
- export DISPLAY=:99.0
- sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
- docker run -v "$PWD/shared:/shared" ...
before_script:
- ng build
script:
- ng test --watch=false
- ng lint
- >
  docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/app --workdir=/app coala/base coala --version
after_success:
- bash ./deploy.sh
- bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
- mv -r coverage/ shared
cache:
    bundler: true
    directories:
    - node_modules
    - .coala-cache
services: docker
branches:
   only:
- angular
```

How should I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you refer to [Codecov Outside Docker](https://github.com/codecov/support/wiki/Testing-with-Docker#codecov-outside-docker). The current error message already tells you that the three dots `...` need to be replaced with a real Docker repository name, e.g. `node:6-alpine`.

What you're still missing is the part of running the tests (including reports) *inside* the Docker container, so that you can `mv` the test reports to the shared folder. You could achieve that by adding a custom Dockerfile based on node, similar to the one below. I chose a more or less full base image including Chrome and other tools to make your use case work:

```
FROM markadams/chromium-xvfb-js:7
WORKDIR /proj
CMD npm install && \
    node_modules/.bin/ng build && \
    node_modules/.bin/ng test --watch=false && \
    node_modules/.bin/ng lint && \
    mkdir -p shared && \
    mv coverage.txt shared
```

That custom image needs to be built and then run like this (assuming the Dockerfile to be in your project root directory):

```
docker build -t ci-build .
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/proj" ci-build
```

I suggest to change the `.travis.yml` like follows:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
language: node_js
node_js:
- 6
before_install:
- docker build -t ci-build .
script:
- >
  docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/proj ci-build
- >
  docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/app --workdir=/app coala/base coala --version
after_success:
- bash ./deploy.sh
- bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
cache:
    bundler: true
    directories:
    - node_modules
    - .coala-cache
services: docker
branches:
   only:
- angular
```

Another note: the `coala/base` image works similarly.

Comment: Thanks for giving time to my question. I really appreciated your help :) I followed the same procedure told by you, but I'm getting error - https://travis-ci.org/fossasia/susper.com/builds/220953875 can you please look and suggest me? It will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I'll have a look at the repo for your PR https://github.com/harshit98/susper.com. Several things are missing inside my proposed Docker image (e.g. Chrome to perform Jasmine tests).

Comment: Yeah. sure. It will be very much helpful for me. I'm not able to generate codecov reports. I have been working on it since 2-3 weeks. @gesellix thanks! :)

Comment: Please see the updated Dockerfile. It runs the build and tests successfully, but I got errors due to a missing `coverage.txt`. That seems to be another issue, though. You should check your build config (or the codecov docs) to fix the generation of that coverage report. Maybe their docs are outdated?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks like 90% of the work has been done! I'm also, getting the errors due to a missing coverage.txt :)