# mv: cannot stat 'coverage.txt': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, docker

I'm trying to setup Codecov in my repository. I'm trying to pass the Codecov reports through docker container.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM markadams/chromium-xvfb-js:7
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
CMD npm install && \
    node_modules/.bin/ng build && \
    node_modules/.bin/ng test --watch=false && \
    node_modules/.bin/ng lint && \
    mkdir -p shared && \
    mv coverage.txt shared
```

The error which I get is this -

```
mv: cannot stat 'coverage.txt': No such file or directory
```

You can check my repository [here](https://github.com/harshit98/susper.com)

Thanks!

Comment: How is this a Docker question, *or* a Linux question? Clearly, `coverage.txt` doesn't exist inside the working directory. That's not indicative of Docker doing anything wrong -- it's rather indicative of your code not having done anything that would create said file in said location.

Comment: Make sure the script and the file have the right permissions, otherwise the script won't be able to "see" the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a file from your build directory to exist inside the image (and containers), you need to first copy the file into your image:

```
FROM markadams/chromium-xvfb-js:7
# add this next line
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
CMD npm install && \
    node_modules/.bin/ng build && \
    node_modules/.bin/ng test --watch=false && \
    node_modules/.bin/ng lint
```

Comment: hey, thanks for giving time to my question. I'm still getting the same error. https://travis-ci.org/fossasia/susper.com/builds/221745017 -check my Travis build report. I have above provided my repo link, you check out my latest commits. Thanks for the help! I really appreciated :)

Comment: I trust you noticed that coverage.txt is not in the top level folder as markan mentioned. I'm going to remove the last two lines of this since it doesn't make sense to create a folder that should have been created in the COPY, and to move a file to a folder that you already placed there in the source repo.

Comment: Removing those last two lines, I think it will effect the Codecov. Since, I'm trying to pass the coverage reports through docker container. So, removing them will not generate any reports as `coverage.txt` has not been mentioned. :)

Comment: Travis build has been passed :)  But no code coverage report has been generated.

Comment: What triggers the report generation? Is the coverage.txt file in the desired location inside your image?

Comment: I was following these rules, https://github.com/codecov/support/wiki/Testing-with-Docker and posted a similar question to it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330235/passing-reports-through-docker-in-codecov-gives-error . Reports are being found but they are not able to be passed through, docker container.

Answer (score 0):

You are moving the coverage.txt to shared. Looking in your repository the file coverage.txt is inside shared.

Therefor you need to do `mv shared/coverage.txt shared`

Comment: Eh? If the destination is a directory name, then the target of `mv` is the current basename inside that directory. Thus, you're telling the OP to run a command equivalent to `mv shared/coverage.txt shared/coverage.txt`; that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hey @markan , thanks for giving time to my question but your solution didn't helped me out. It was giving the same error as mentioned in above comment. :)